# Is normal that a web site which use OpenID as SSO sends all the cookie without samesite header?

Tags: sso, openid

Is normal that a web site which uses OpenID as SSO sends all the cookie without `samesite` header?
Is this required in order to make OpenID work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usage of cookies in OAuth and OpenID Connect**
There are two kind of cookies used in SSO context: Authorization Server (AS) cookies and Client cookies (the web service is called client in this context). I think you refere to the latter one.

In OAuth, cookies are traditionally used in combination with the `state` parameter to protect against CSRF, as written in the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12) (which also explains the basic CSRF scenario):

> The client MUST implement CSRF protection for its redirection URI.
> This is typically accomplished by requiring any request sent to the
> redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request to
> the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g., a hash of the session
> cookie used to authenticate the user-agent).  The client SHOULD
> utilize the "state" request parameter to deliver this value to the
> authorization server when making an authorization request.

For OpenID Connect, the `state` parameter is used exactly the same way, as stated in the [OpenID Connect Core Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest):

> state: RECOMMENDED. Opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback. Typically, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF, XSRF) mitigation is done by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie.

Further, OpenID Connect also uses a `nonce` parameter, which can be also used in combination with a cookie, c.f. Section [15.5.2.](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#NonceNotes):

> The nonce parameter value needs to include per-session state [...] One method to achieve this for Web Server Clients is to store a cryptographically random value as an HttpOnly session cookie and use a cryptographic hash of the value as the nonce parameter. In that case, the nonce in the returned ID Token is compared to the hash of the session cookie to detect ID Token replay by third parties. A related method applicable to JavaScript Clients is to store the cryptographically random value in HTML5 local storage and use a cryptographic hash of this value.

So I would not agree with [Conors first point](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239574/247748) and would resume that it is nothing special a service implementing OpenID Connect SSO uses cookies.

**Function of SameSite Cookies**
The [SameSite Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) is primarly protecting *the cookie* against CSRF. As [Conor worte in his answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239574/247748), this is a relatively new cookie option introduced in 2016. Recent changes in its specification (2020) changed the default value to `SameSite=Lax`, which delivers a decent protection against CSRF even if SameSite is not set explicitly.

**Is a SameSite Cookie needed to secure OpenID Connect?**
Clearly, it is possible to implement OpenID Connect with `SameSite cookies`. But the lack of a `SameSite=Strict` parameter does not mean that the site is vulnerable. There might be reasons to use only the `SameSite=Lax` protection. There are also secure ways to not use any cookies, e.g. [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) is a secure ([and recommended](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-16#section-2.1.1)) alternative to the cookie usage scenarios named above.

Answer (score 1):

OpenID and SSO should not introduce any cookie requirements at all. With all SSO login systems I have seen the user information comes back in URL parameters when the user is sent back to the website after login. Therefore, even using cookies in the first place is not typically required for these things.

However, the `samesite` cookie property is relatively new. As a result it is probably just missing because the person/people managing the site simply haven't thought to implement it.